# How do I write an enumeration in F# without explicitly assigning number literals?

Tags: f#, enums

I have an enumeration in F#, like this:

```
type Creature =
   | SmallCreature = 0
   | MediumCreature = 1
   | GiantCreature = 2
   | HumongousCreature = 3
   | CreatureOfNondescriptSize = 4
```

I do not like manually typing out numbers, and I want to easily insert more items in the enumeration later without having to shift the numbers.

I tried this

```
type Creature =
   | SmallCreature
   | MediumCreature
   | GiantCreature
   | HumongousCreature
   | CreatureOfNondescriptSize
```

but it caused an error `The type 'Creature' is not a CLI enum type` later in the program

```
let input = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine())
let output = match EnumOfValue<int, Creature>(input) with // <---Error occurs here
    | Creature.SmallCreature -> "Rat"
    | Creature.MediumCreature -> "Dog"
    | Creature.GiantCreature -> "Elephant"
    | Creature.HumongousCreature -> "Whale"
    | Creature.CreatureOfNondescriptSize -> "Jon Skeet"
    | _ -> "Unacceptably Hideous Monstrosity"

Console.WriteLine(output)
Console.WriteLine()
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...")
Console.Read() |> ignore
```

How can I define an enumeration without manually assigning number values to each item?

Comment: Although I don't consider DUs to be a drop-in replacement for enums, if you go that route you might consider marking your type with [`[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340423.aspx), since DU cases are top-level members of the enclosing namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. Are the numeric values important? If so, it somewhat escapes the intended use of enums (flags aside). You might consider a class or discriminated union in that case.

Your second example is, in fact, a discriminated union. But your later use of `EnumOfValue`, which expects an enum, is causing the error.

Another option is to store the enum to number mapping in a dictionary and replace the pattern matching with a dictionary lookup. Then, the numeric value of the enum would be irrelevant.

I agree that manually managing enum values is burdensome. I hope it's addressed in a future version.

Answer (score 4):

As Daniel says, you can't define an enum without specifying the numeric equivalents.  However, you *can* define a function which converts a number to the corresponding case of a discriminated union:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let intToDU<'t> n =
    if not (FSharpType.IsUnion typeof<'t>) then
        failwithf "%s is not a discriminated union" typeof<'t>.Name
    let cases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<'t>)
    if n >= cases.Length || n < 0 then
        failwithf "%i is out of the range of %s's cases (0 - %i)" n typeof<'t>.Name (cases.Length - 1)
    let uc = cases.[n]
    if uc.GetFields().Length > 0 then 
        failwithf "%s.%s requires constructor arguments" typeof<'t>.Name uc.Name
    FSharpValue.MakeUnion(uc, [||]) :?> 't
```

Then you can use this generic function like this:

```
type Creature =   
| SmallCreature   
| MediumCreature   
| GiantCreature   
| HumongousCreature   
| CreatureOfNondescriptSize

let input = int (System.Console.ReadLine())

let output = 
    match intToDU input with 
    | SmallCreature -> "Rat"    
    | Creature.MediumCreature -> "Dog"    
    | Creature.GiantCreature -> "Elephant"    
    | Creature.HumongousCreature -> "Whale"    
    | Creature.CreatureOfNondescriptSize -> "Jon Skeet"
```

This has the added benefit that the pattern match is now total.

Comment: Is there any way to get at the `Tags` inner class (or `Tag` property on the case) that's visible in C#? That would make this possible without using reflection.

Comment: @Daniel - not to my knowledge.  However, I don't see how that would help: you could use the Tag value to convert from the DU to int, but not vice versa (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: It would still require a function to go from int to DU, but it could be done without reflection, or a dependency on case order. It wouldn't be a huge improvement. I'm mostly just curious.

Comment: Do you know if there are plans to address this? Maybe an `[<AutoAssignValues>]` attribute? :-) I suppose that still leaves the syntactic ambiguity with DUs. Maybe an `[<Enum>]` attribute would resolve that, much like `[<AbstractClass>]` resolves the ambiguity with interfaces.

Comment: @Daniel - I don't know if there are plans to address it, but I've never found it particularly burdensome - usually I prefer DUs anyway since they give you total matching.