# F# enum to string conversion

Tags: enums, f#

I have a following `F#` `enum`

```
type DataType = AUCTION|TRANSACTION
```

I would like to use `DataType` as a parameter to a function, so that the values of the parameter is restricted to string `AUCTION` and `TRANSACTION`,

is that possible to convert the items in this `enum` to `string`, or is there a better way to contraint the value of a parameter to a set of `string`?

Comment: Have you looked for other SO questions or outside SO with the keywords `F# constrain parameter DU`? If not please do so. If any of them look close but do not work please add them to the question and explain why they do not work. That is what I am doing right now. This smells of a duplicate question.

Comment: Note that `DataType` is not an enum... it is a discriminated union. And thus you should use pattern matching.

Comment: Does this work for you? [F# type constraints on enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115050/f-type-constraints-on-enums) Also see: [F# – Enums vs Discriminated Unions](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/10/fsharp-enums-vs-discriminated-unions/)

Comment: Or this: [Working around incomplete pattern matching on enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075322/working-around-incomplete-pattern-matching-on-enums/6128810#6128810)

Comment: Also see: [How do I write an enumeration in F# without explicitly assigning number literals?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083598/how-do-i-write-an-enumeration-in-f-without-explicitly-assigning-number-literals)

Comment: You can use the `string` function to convert values to string values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, as several people have mentioned in the comments, the type you have defined is not an *Enumeration*, it's a *Discriminated Union.*

Enumerations are effectively just a label given to an integer and, in F#, are declared using this syntax:

```
type DataType = 
    |Auction = 1
    |Transaction = 2
```

Using this syntax, you've got a relationship between the value and the associated integer, you can use the integer to get the value of an Enumeration, e.g.

```
let transaction = enum<DataType>(2) // Transaction
```

Note that there is nothing stopping you from saying `enum<DataType>(3537)`, even though we haven't defined that case.

For more details on Enumerations, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233216.aspx

---

Discriminated Unions are much more flexible than Enumerations.  Let's take a look at yours:

```
type DataType = 
    |Auction
    |Transaction
```

This version is now actually a Standard .NET class with two *case identifiers*: `Auction` and `Transaction`.  You can think of Auction and Transaction as two *type constructors* for `DataType`.

Discriminated Unions are not restricted to just simple cases, you could store additional data, e.g.

```
type DataType = 
    /// An auction with a list of bids
    |Auction of Bid list  
    /// A transaction with some price in GBP
    |Transaction of decimal<GBP>
```

With Disciminated Unions, there is no implicit relationships with integers, if we want to construct a particular case, we have to use the appropriate *case identifier*.

e.g. `let auction = Auction (bidlist)`

For more details on Discriminated Unions, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx

---

In both cases, converting to a specific string for each case can be achieved using pattern matching.

For the Discriminated Union:

```
let datatypeToString datatype =
    match datatype with
    |Auction -> "AUCTION"
    |Transaction -> "TRANSACTION"
```

And for the Enumeration:

```
let datatypeToString datatype =
    match datatype with
    |DataType.Auction -> "AUCTION"
    |DataType.Transaction -> "TRANSACTION"
```

Notice that when you use Enumerations, F# will give you a compiler warning telling you that pattern matches cases aren't complete.  This is because Enumerations are just `int`s and there are many `int`s besides just 1 and 2, this means that the match cases aren't exhaustive.

I therefore recommend you stick to Discriminated Unions and keep your exhaustive pattern matching.

---

P.S. If you want to go in the other direction, from `string` to `DataType`, I recommend using a `tryCreateDataType` function which would look something like this:

```
let tryCreateDataType str =
    match str with
    |"AUCTION" -> Some Auction
    |"TRANSACTION" -> Some Transaction
    |_ -> None
```

This returns an `Option`, so it will allow you to safely match against the function being successful or it failing due to an invalid string.